# Icons have disappeared

Tags: magento-1.9, product

My icons eg add to cart as well as arrows on moving banners have disappeared.
Please refer to the pic attached (product3). How do I make it right?

Thanks[image]

Comment: Please clear more. or link plz for check.

Comment: Its looks like you are using font-awesome for icons and its not loading check console i sure there you will find out issue

Answer (score 2):

### **Font-awesome :**

If you are using **font-awesome** check this points:

1) Assure you use a correct link to the CDN, such as:

```
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" 
  rel="stylesheet"  type='text/css'>
```

2) If you are using **HTTPS**, do you link to the font-awesome CSS using HTTPS (replace http:// with https:// in the link above).

3) Check that you don't have AdBlock enabled. They might be blocking some of the icons.

4) Reset your browsers cache.

5) Assure that the `<span>` or `<i>` element you use, uses the FontAwesome font family. For example : `<i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

It won't work if you have something as the following in your CSS:

```
* {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif !important;   
}
```

### **Media Icon :**

1) If you use some icons that you have stored on your server, check if you don't delete them or move them by mistake.

2) Check also the CSS related to this icones.